# How can I concatenate multiple files of different file formats into one such that all source files open when I open the final file?

Tags: windows, merge, concatenation, file-manipulation

I am working on is creating a Bitmap image which if opened changes the desktop Wallpaper to itself. I have a Bitmap image and VBS script which sets it as the wallpaper. I want to merge them together to a single file which when opened sets the image as the Desktop Background.

I wish to do it for Windows.

Comment: Can you be more specific where your problem is? Is it that you don't know how to attach a bitmap as a resource?

Comment: There's no such thing as merging files on Windows to make them all open in Explorer when you double-click.  But you can write a script or program that when run will open all of the files.  It can be a batch file, or you can just add it to your VBS.

Comment: @RyanBemrose, I tried doing that. But I wish to send it to users who can change their wallpapers this way. But VBS script can't be transferred on the internet. so I wanted to make an image which sets itself as the wallpaper when opened. is there any way of doing that?

Comment: If you can't transfer a certain type of file, that's a very different problem.  Your best bet is to put them all into a [self-extracting archive](https://superuser.com/q/42788)

Comment: Imagine if it were possible to create an image file that sets itself as your wallpaper when you open it. People could create web pages that change your wallpaper just by visiting the web site!